# Check if an option is selected and edit HTML markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to check if an option I've chosen is selected. The script is very simple: If the `<select>` is set to `other` then the `message` field becomes mandatory (an asterisk appears).

It works but ... I wonder how to organize it if we have 10 cases like this in the same page.

```
<div class="field-select">
   <label for="" class="field-label">Select an option : *</label>
   <select class="js-select-motif">
      <option value="">I am not satisfied with your services</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
   </select>
</div>

<div class="field-textarea">
   <div class="field-label">Comment : <span class="asterisk is-hidden">*</span>
   </div>
   <textarea name="" id="" class="js-textarea" placeholder="Add comment here"></textarea>
</div>
```

```
const $selectMotif = $('.js-select-motif');

if ($('.js-select-motif').length > 0) {
  $selectMotif.change(function () {
    if($selectMotif.val() == 'other') {
      $('.asterisk').removeClass('is-hidden');
    } else {
      $('.asterisk').addClass('is-hidden');
    }
  })
}
```

Demo available on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/lorraineS/pen/PoYZPMr)

Thanks

Comment: have you looked into `:selected`? https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Comment: Yes. But selecting option is not the problem. The problem comes from `.asterisk` organization, especially when we have this HTML markup applied multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Revised approach, based on my — hopefully correct — re-reading of the question:

```js
// here we find all <select> elements that contain an <option> whose
// value is equal to "other", and then we bind the anonymous function
// of the on() method as the event-handler for the 'change' event:
$('select:has(option[value="other"])').on('change', function() {

  // we cache the $(this) jQuery object in the similarly-named
  // $this variable:
  const $this = $(this);

  // from the $(this) we navigate to the closest <div> and then
  // to the next sibling element:
  $this.closest('div').next()
    // within that sibling we find the descendant elements which
    // match the supplied selector:
    .find('.asterisk')
    // and then we toggle the 'is-hidden' class according to the
    // switch; if $(this).val() is anything other than 'other'
    // the 'is-hidden' class will be applied; if the value is
    // equal to 'other' the assessment will be false, and the
    // 'is-hidden' class will be removed (making the asterisk
    // visible):
    .toggleClass('is-hidden', $this.val() !== 'other');

  // here we trigger the change() event on page-load to show/hide
  // appropriately:
}).change();
```

```css
.asterisk {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.asterisk.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field-select">
  <label for="" class="field-label">Select an option : *</label>
  <select class="js-select-motif">
    <option value="">I am not satisfied with your services</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="field-textarea">
  <div class="field-label">Comment : <span class="asterisk is-hidden">*</span>
  </div>
  <textarea class="js-textarea" placeholder="Add comment here"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="field-select">
  <label for="" class="field-label">Select an option : *</label>
  <select class="js-select-motif">
    <option value="">I am not satisfied with your services</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="field-textarea">
  <div class="field-label">Comment : <span class="asterisk is-hidden">*</span>
  </div>
  <textarea class="js-textarea" placeholder="Add comment here"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="field-select">
  <label for="" class="field-label">Select an option : *</label>
  <select class="js-select-motif">
    <option value="">I am not satisfied with your services</option>
    <option value="no other">No other</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="field-textarea">
  <div class="field-label">Comment : <span class="asterisk is-hidden">*</span>
  </div>
  <textarea class="js-textarea" placeholder="Add comment here"></textarea>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/67rw1b5d/3/).

With plain JavaScript, an alternative approach could be:

```js
// find all <select> elements with an option of 'other':
// here we use spread syntax ('...') to convert the NodeList of <option> elements
// returned by document.querySelectorAll() into an Array:
const selects = [...document.querySelectorAll('option')].filter(
    // we filter that Array to retain only the <option> elements
    // whose value property is equal to 'other':
    (opt) => opt.value === 'other'
  ).map(
    // we then create an Array of <select> elements, using 
    // Element.closest() to navigate up through the DOM to
    // the closest element that matches the supplied selector:
    (opt) => opt.closest('select')
  ),
  // here we define the function that will handle the show/hide of the
  // relevant element(s); the Event Object is passed to the function
  // automatically from the later use of EventTarget.addEventListener():
  toggleMessage = (event) => {

    // we retrieve the eleemt to which the event was bound (the <select>
    // element in this case):
    const changed = event.currentTarget,

      // we find the nextElementSibling (because there's no other relationship
      // we're dependant on the DOM structure to identify which textarea element
      // is related to which <select> element):
      neighbour = changed.closest('.field-select').nextElementSibling,

      // we find all descendant elements of the neigbour that match
      // the supplied selector (if you know for certain there will
      // only ever be one matching element then you could instead use
      // neighbour.querySelector('.asterisk'), which will return only
      // the first matching element or null if none are found):
      asterisks = neighbour.querySelectorAll('.asterisk'),

      // we derive a Boolean (true/false) from the assessment of the value
      // of the <select> element:
      boolSwitch = changed.value !== 'other';

    // because we used document.querySelectorAll() we have to iterate over
    // the returned NodeList, using NodeList.prototype.forEach():
    asterisks.forEach(
      // here 'aster' is a reference to the current Node in the NodeList
      // over whcih we're iterating; we use Element.classList API to toggle
      // the 'is-hidden' class depending on the boolSwitch. If the boolSwitch
      // is true (and the <select> value is _not_ 'other') we add the class-name
      // otherwise we remove it (adding an already-present class, or removing
      // an already-absent class causes no error):
      (aster) => aster.classList.toggle('is-hidden', boolSwitch)
    );

  },

  // in order to trigger the event, so that the elements are shown/hidden
  // on page-load, we create change Event object:
  changeEvent = new Event('change');

// here we iterate over the <selct> elements found eariler:
selects.forEach(
  (select) => {
    // here we add the toggleMessagE() function as the event-handler for
    // the 'change' event:
    select.addEventListener('change', toggleMessage);

    // we triogger the custom change event to trigger the appropriate
    // display state on page-load:
    select.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
  });
```

```css
.asterisk {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.asterisk.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="field-select">
  <label for="" class="field-label">Select an option : *</label>
  <select class="js-select-motif">
    <option value="">I am not satisfied with your services</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="field-textarea">
  <div class="field-label">Comment : <span class="asterisk is-hidden">*</span>
  </div>
  <textarea class="js-textarea" placeholder="Add comment here"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="field-select">
  <label for="" class="field-label">Select an option : *</label>
  <select class="js-select-motif">
    <option value="">I am not satisfied with your services</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="field-textarea">
  <div class="field-label">Comment : <span class="asterisk is-hidden">*</span>
  </div>
  <textarea class="js-textarea" placeholder="Add comment here"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="field-select">
  <label for="" class="field-label">Select an option : *</label>
  <select class="js-select-motif">
    <option value="">I am not satisfied with your services</option>
    <option value="no other">No other</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="field-textarea">
  <div class="field-label">Comment : <span class="asterisk is-hidden">*</span>
  </div>
  <textarea class="js-textarea" placeholder="Add comment here"></textarea>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/67rw1b5d/4/).

---

Original answer below, which was my misreading of the question (though it may be useful to others in different contexts):

One approach, using plain JavaScript:

```js
// find all <select> elements with an option of 'other':
// here we use spread syntax ('...') to convert the NodeList of <option> elements
// returned by document.querySelectorAll() into an Array:
const selects = [...document.querySelectorAll('option')].filter(
    // we filter that Array to retain only the <option> elements
    // whose value property is equal to 'other':
    (opt) => opt.value === 'other'
  ).map(
    // we then create an Array of <select> elements, using 
    // Element.closest() to navigate up through the DOM to
    // the closest element that matches the supplied selector:
    (opt) => opt.closest('select')
  ),
  // here we define the function that will handle the show/hide of the
  // relevant element(s); the Event Object is passed to the function
  // automatically from the later use of EventTarget.addEventListener():
  toggleMessage = (event) => {

    // we retrieve the eleemt to which the event was bound (the <select>
    // element in this case):
    const changed = event.currentTarget,

      // we find the nextElementSibling (because there's no other relationship
      // we're dependant on the DOM structure to identify which textarea element
      // is related to which <select> element):
      neighbour = changed.closest('.field-select').nextElementSibling,

      // we derive a Boolean (true/false) from the assessment of the value
      // of the <select> element:
      boolSwitch = changed.value === 'other';

    // we update the display of the relevant neighbour element, uisng a
    // conditional ('ternary') operator; if the boolSwitch is true then
    // the display is updated to 'block', otherwise it's updated to 'none':
    neighbour.style.display = boolSwitch ? 'block' : 'none';

  },

  // in order to trigger the event, so that the elements are shown/hidden
  // on page-load, we create change Event object:
  changeEvent = new Event('change');

// here we iterate over the <selct> elements found eariler:
selects.forEach(
  (select) => {
    // here we add the toggleMessagE() function as the event-handler for
    // the 'change' event:
    select.addEventListener('change', toggleMessage);

    // we triogger the custom change event to trigger the appropriate
    // display state on page-load:
    select.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
  });
```

```html
<div class="field-select">
  <label for="" class="field-label">Select an option : *</label>
  <select class="js-select-motif">
    <option value="">I am not satisfied with your services</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="field-textarea">
  <div class="field-label">Comment : <span class="asterisk is-hidden">*</span>
  </div>
  <textarea class="js-textarea" placeholder="Add comment here"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="field-select">
  <label for="" class="field-label">Select an option : *</label>
  <select class="js-select-motif">
    <option value="">I am not satisfied with your services</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="field-textarea">
  <div class="field-label">Comment : <span class="asterisk is-hidden">*</span>
  </div>
  <textarea class="js-textarea" placeholder="Add comment here"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="field-select">
  <label for="" class="field-label">Select an option : *</label>
  <select class="js-select-motif">
    <option value="">I am not satisfied with your services</option>
    <option value="no other">No other</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="field-textarea">
  <div class="field-label">Comment : <span class="asterisk is-hidden">*</span>
  </div>
  <textarea class="js-textarea" placeholder="Add comment here"></textarea>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/67rw1b5d/).

Or, using jQuery:

```js
// here we find all <select> elements that contain an <option> whose
// value is equal to "other", and then we bind the anonymous function
// of the on() method as the event-handler for the 'change' event:
$('select:has(option[value="other"])').on('change', function() {

  // we cache the $(this) in a similarly-named variable:
  const $this = $(this);

  // we navigate from the $(this) to the closest ancestor <div>
  // element, then to the next sibling element and bind the toggle()
  // method to it, uisng the switch option:
  $this.closest('div').next().toggle(
    // here we hide the <div> element if the current value of the
    // <select> is 'other' (the 'switch' evaluates to true); or
    // show it if the switch evaluates to false
    $this.val() === 'other'
  );

  // here we trigger the change() event on page-load to show/hide
  // appropriately:
}).change();
```

```html
<div class="field-select">
  <label for="" class="field-label">Select an option : *</label>
  <select class="js-select-motif">
    <option value="">I am not satisfied with your services</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="field-textarea">
  <div class="field-label">Comment : <span class="asterisk is-hidden">*</span>
  </div>
  <textarea class="js-textarea" placeholder="Add comment here"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="field-select">
  <label for="" class="field-label">Select an option : *</label>
  <select class="js-select-motif">
    <option value="">I am not satisfied with your services</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="field-textarea">
  <div class="field-label">Comment : <span class="asterisk is-hidden">*</span>
  </div>
  <textarea class="js-textarea" placeholder="Add comment here"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="field-select">
  <label for="" class="field-label">Select an option : *</label>
  <select class="js-select-motif">
    <option value="">I am not satisfied with your services</option>
    <option value="no other">No other</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="field-textarea">
  <div class="field-label">Comment : <span class="asterisk is-hidden">*</span>
  </div>
  <textarea class="js-textarea" placeholder="Add comment here"></textarea>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/67rw1b5d/2/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [Arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [Conditional ('ternary') Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
  - [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.classList()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
  - [`Event()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event).
  - [`Event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).
  - [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).
  - [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement).
  - [`NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling).
  - [Spread (`[...]`) syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
- jQuery:

  - [`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/).
  - [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/).
  - [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/).
  - [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/).
  - [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [$.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

> The **.each()** method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise
>   and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements
>   that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is
>   passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly,
>   the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so
>   the keyword this refers to the element.

```js
$('.field-group').each(function(i, e){
  //$(e) is the element itself
  const $selectMotif = $(e).find('.js-select-motif');  
  if ($selectMotif.length > 0) {
    $selectMotif.change(function () {
      if($selectMotif.val() == 'other') {
         $(e).find('.asterisk').removeClass('is-hidden');
      } else {
         $(e).find('.asterisk').addClass('is-hidden');
      }
    })
  }
  })
```

```css
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.field-item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.field-label {
  color: #6D6F81;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.field-select {
  select {
    height: 50px;
    appearance: none;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
}
.red{color:red}

.field-textarea {
  textarea {
    border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field-group">
  <div class="field-item">
    <div class="field-select">
      <label for="" class="field-label">Select an option : *</label>
      <select class="js-select-motif">
        <option value="">I am not satisfied with your services</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field-item">
    <div class="field-textarea">
      <div class="field-label">Comment : <span class="red asterisk is-hidden">*</span></div>
      <textarea name="" id="" class="js-textarea" placeholder="Add comment here..."></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="field-label">required *</div>
<hr />
<div class="field-group">
  <div class="field-item">
    <div class="field-select">
      <label for="" class="field-label">Select an option : *</label>
      <select class="js-select-motif">
        <option value="">I am not satisfied with your services</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field-item">
    <div class="field-textarea">
      <div class="field-label">Comment : <span class="red asterisk is-hidden">*</span></div>
      <textarea name="" id="" class="js-textarea" placeholder="Add comment here..."></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="field-label">required *</div>
```